# Sum values of Dataframe based on qcuts of a second Dataframe over axis 1

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'd like to sum the values of dataframe `A` over `axis=1` masked on the [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) bins of dataframe `B` computed over `axis=1`.

`A` and `B` have identical indices and columns. The values of `q` could be different to those given in the example. Dataframe `B` can have `NaN`s.

#### Example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [4, 8, -2, -6, 7, -3, 4],
     'b': [-8, 8, 6, 6, 5, -3, -2],
     'e': [1, 34, -13, 5, 0, 8, -76],
     'c': [1, 2, 6, 3, 8, -4, -20],
     'd': [4, 0, 3, -4, 8, 4, 2]})
B = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [34, 78, -2, -96, np.nan, -34, 44],
     'b': [-82, 28, 96, 46, np.nan, -3, -20],
     'e': [12, 324, -123, 56, np.nan, 8, -876],
     'c': [np.nan, 28, 96, np.nan, 8, -34, -20],
     'd': [42, -40, 23, -40, -50, 10, 97]})
q = [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1]
```

```
out = 
      0    1     2
0  -8.0  1.0   8.0
1  10.0  0.0  42.0
2 -15.0  3.0  12.0
3  -6.0 -4.0  11.0
4   8.0  0.0   8.0
5  -7.0 -3.0  12.0
6 -98.0  0.0   6.0
```

#### Approach

One possible approach which *seems* to work is,

```py
bins = B.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q, labels=False), axis=1)
out = pd.concat(
      [A.mask(bins!=x, np.nan).sum(axis=1) for x in range(len(q)-1)],
      axis=1)
```

however this is very slow. The majority of time is used in applying the qcuts.

#### Timing

My dataframe is approximately 3000 rows by 500 columns and applying the qcuts takes 2.7 seconds with a further 130 milli-seconds taken in summing.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
D = 3000
C = 500
dt_index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=D)
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(D,C), index=dt_index)
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(D,C), index=dt_index)
q = [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1]
```

```py
%timeit bins = B.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q, labels=False), axis=1)
2.74 s ± 147 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%timeit out = pd.concat([A.mask(bins!=x, np.nan).sum(axis=1) for x in range(len(q)-1)], axis=1)
131 ms ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Is there a significantly faster way to achieve the same result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Overview and result

Interesting question. `pd.qcut()` is a nice function. If you are looking for something faster, you might want to take a look at a numpy implementation. Unfortunately, numpy does not seem to have the exact same function. A combination of `np.nanpercentile()` and `np.digitize()` could work. But it handles NaNs and bins a little bit differently than Pandas. So you will need some extra (ugly) handling to make sure you have exactly the same result as the original implementation. I tested 3 implementations:

- Your implementation (variable `bins`): 1460 ms
- Implementation with a numpy loop (variable `bins2`): 590 ms
- Implementation with numpy list comprehension (variable `bins3`): 325 ms

To make sure the end result is the same, you can parse the resulting dataframes to a nullable Int64 type and use the `df.equals()` function.

#### Numpy loop:

```
def makeBins2(df, q):
    # Use nanpercentile as there are NaNs in the original dataframe
    numpy_quantiles = np.nanpercentile(df, np.array(q)*100, axis=1).T
    df_nparray = df.to_numpy()
    
    myList = []
    for i in range(0,len(df_nparray)):
        row = df_nparray[i]
        np_cut = numpy_quantiles[i]
        # Correct for 0-start vs 1-start
        result = np.digitize(row, np_cut, right=True) -1
        
        # Correct for NaNs and left side
        result = np.where(result>(len(q)-2), np.nan, result)
        result = np.where(result<0, 0, result)
        myList.append(result)
        
        
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=list(df))
    df_out.index = df.index
    return df_out
```

#### Numpy list comprehension:

```
def row_function(row, q):
    data = row[:-len(q)]
    np_cut = row[-len(q):]
    result = np.digitize(data, np_cut, right=True) -1
    
    # Correct for NaNs and left side borders
    result = np.where(result>(len(q)-2), np.nan, result)
    result = np.where(result<0, 0, result)
    return result
    
    
def makeBins3(df, q):
    # Use nanpercentile as there are NaNs in the original dataframe
    numpy_quantiles = np.nanpercentile(df, np.array(q)*100, axis=1).T
    npArray = df.to_numpy()
    
    # Make a single np matrix for row comprehension   
    npAll = np.concatenate((npArray, numpy_quantiles),axis=1)
    
    # List comprehension
    myList = np.array(([row_function(x,q) for x in npAll]))
               
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=list(df))
    df_out.index = df.index
    return df_out
```

#### Check result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

D = 3000
C = 500
dt_index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=D)
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(D,C), index=dt_index)
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(D,C), index=dt_index)
q = [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1]

bins = B.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, q, labels=False), axis=1)
bins2 = makeBins2(B,q)
bins3 = makeBins3(B,q)

print(bins.astype(pd.Int64Dtype()).equals(bins2.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())))
print(bins.astype(pd.Int64Dtype()).equals(bins3.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())))
```

Comment: Thank you! I find your second numpy list comprehension solution a really very interesting approach. I guess more generally, `result>2`, should be `result>(len(q)-2)`?